# Need advice on a semi-classical derivation of the magnetic Schwinger limit

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics, semiclassical

I'm trying to formulate with some rigor a semi-classical definition of the *Schwinger limit* on magnetic field strenght, but there are holes that need to be patched.  Currently, the following formulation isn't satisfying and I need help on this.

Consider an electron dropped into an *uniform static magnetic field*.  The initial velocity is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines.  From Newton'equation (taking special relativity into account), the electron will follow a circular path of radius
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
r = \frac{\gamma \, m_0 \, v}{e B} \equiv \frac{p}{e B}.
\end{equation}
This relation shows that if the field $B$ is very strong, the radius will be small : $r \rightarrow 0$ when $B \rightarrow \infty$.  For a given field, the radius will also be small if the momentum $p$ is small : $r \rightarrow 0$ when $p \rightarrow 0$.

The *classical circular motion* is well defined only when the uncertainties are relatively small : $r \gg \Delta r$ and $p \gg \Delta p$. The motion will be *quantum mechanical* (i.e circular motion not well defined) when the field is very strong and the momentum low enough : $r \approx \Delta r_{\text{min}}$ and $p \approx \Delta p_{\text{min}}$ (by symetry of the circular motion, I'm assuming $\Delta x = \Delta y \approx \Delta r$ and $\Delta p_x = \Delta p_y \approx \Delta p$, **which I feel unsafe**). So (1) could define the quantum mechanical regime :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\Delta r_{\text{min}} \approx \frac{\Delta p_{\text{min}}}{e B}.
\end{equation}
The Heisenberg uncertainty principle imposes a constraint on the value of $\Delta r_{\text{min}}$ and $\Delta p_{\text{min}}$ :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\Delta r_{\text{min}} \, \Delta p_{\text{min}} \approx \frac{\hbar}{2}.
\end{equation}
Substituting (2) into (3) give this contraint on the magnetic field, to get a quantum mechanical regime :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
B \approx \frac{2 \Delta p_{\text{min}}^2}{e \hbar}.
\end{equation}
Currently, the uncertainty $\Delta p_{\text{min}}$ is arbitrary.  The motion will be quantum mechanical as soon as $p \approx \Delta p_{\text{min}}$ *and* (4) are satisfied.  The particle's motion will be *quantum relativistic* when $p \approx \Delta p_{\text{min}} \approx m_0 \, c$, so (4) becomes
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
B \approx \frac{2 m_0^2 \, c^2}{e \hbar},
\end{equation}
which is the **Schwinger limit** (up to a factor of 2).  For magnetic fields stronger than this, the particle's motion will be ultra-relativistic.

> Now, *there's something fishy* with this derivation that I don't see
>   clearly.  What is wrong with this reasoning ?  Where are the holes in the derivation shown above ?  Also, is there a simpler way of getting (5), with some rigor in the reasoning ?

The problem may lies in the physical interpretation and wordings, not just in the maths (which are easy).

---

**EDIT :** It's simpler and more accurate (?) to use the angular momentum instead of Heisenberg principle :
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
L = r \, p = \frac{p^2}{e B} \approx \hbar.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The uncertainty principle you used is for one dimension, but I believe the orbit of the electron must be defined in two. If you are assuming  $\Delta x$ ***is equal to*** $\Delta y$, then they both must equal $\Delta r/\sqrt{2}$. The same would go for $p$, so in the situation, you are describing:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta r_{min}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\Delta p_{min}}{\sqrt{2}} \approx \frac{\hbar}{2},
\end{equation}
so then
\begin{equation}
\Delta r_{min}\Delta p_{min}\approx \hbar.
\end{equation}
Following this through to the end of your derivation yields the correct limit.